# JQuery Order list by field and add to divider div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get listing organized by a field called letter.

So the fields are:

id, name, letter.

for example:

### id   name   letter

1    list1  a
2    list2  a
3    list3  b

To list1 and list2 are added after id="a" and list3 is added after id="b"

Here is a json data sample:

```
{"id":[{"id":"1","name":"list1","letter":"a"},{"id":"2","name":"list2","letter":"b"}]}
```

The code below adds the contents to the listview but I need to go a step further and add then to their own place.

For example all listings with the letter "a" are added after the A etc

Here is the code:

```
$.getJSON("list.json", function(data){
    var output = '';

    $.each(data.id, function(index, value){

        output += '<li><h1>' + value.name + '</h1></li>';

    });


    $('#listview').html(output).listview('refresh');

    }).error(function(args) {
console.log(args);

});

<ul id="listview">
<li id="a">A</li>
<!--Listings with letter A go here-->
<li id="b">B</li>
<!--Listings with letter B go here-->
<li id="c">C</li>
<!--Listings with letter C go here-->
</ul>
```

How can I get the listings for be added to its place?

Comment: how does you json looks like?

Comment: I have added some sample json data. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.each(data.id, function(index, value){ 

    $('<li><h1>' + value.name + '</h1></li>').insertAfter('#' + value.letter);

});
```

Comment: actually it is :

$('<li><h1>' + value.name + '</h1></li>').insertAfter('#' + value.letter);

Comment: I replaced: this: output += '<li><h1>' + value.name + '</h1></li>';
 with your code:  $('#' + value.letter).insertAfter('<li><h1>' + value.name + '</h1></li>'); but nothing shows in the listview.

Comment: Nothing is added to the listview ... The data is in output - output += '<li><h1>' + value.name + '</h1></li>';

Comment: this example works for me. Please check out this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cYEuD/

Answer (score 0):

```
​var startstring = value.name.substring(0,1);

var outputA,outputB,outputC;
$.each(data.id, function(index, value){
    var startstring = value.name.substring(0,1);
    if(startstring == 'A'){

        outputA += '<li><h1>' + value.name + '</h1></li>';
    }
    if(startstring == 'B')
        outputB += '<li><h1>' + value.name + '</h1></li>';
    if(startstring == 'C')
        outputC += '<li><h1>' + value.name + '</h1></li>';


    });
$('#listview').append(outputA);
$('#listview').append(outputB);
$('#listview').append(outputC);
```